# How to detect error when not connected to mail server from Django?

Tags: django, email, server

I have the following in my `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_PORT = 567
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I have the following code to send email:

```
email = EmailMessage()
email.subject = subject
email.body = body
email.from_email = from_email
email.to = to
email.attach(file_name, pdf, 'application/pdf')    
email.send()
```

Sometimes our server is down and there is no way for me to detect if the mail was sent or not. One way I can think of is to show `Mail not sent` error when Django cannot connect to mail server. How can I detect a failed connection to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try except.

```
try:
    email.send()
except Exception as e:
    print str(e.message)
    # you can do some action.
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I have tried to return False when exception occurs. But when I use that return boolean value to execute a code it gets executed regardless of the value.

Comment: `str(e.message)` will give you error message. If you `return False` then it will simply execute. But if you are executing send email via function then it will return you that Boolean value. Can you share you try except code.

Comment: I have figured out what is wrong. I am returning boolean from a celery task, which returns an AsyncResult instance and not a boolean. Thus, it is always true in my view where I capture the return value. However, I don't know how to get a boolean from Celery task and I feel solving this will solve my problem. I don't think there is a problem with my try except clause, I just copied your code.